# How can I set "If" statement with nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`country` attribute's default value is nil.

In countries table, some record has `image_url`, and the rest of the record's `country` attributes are nil.

So I coded this in helper

```
def image(user)
    if user.country.image_url
        image_tag "flags/#{user.country.image_url}.png" 
    end
end
```

However, it returns error when `image_url` was nil

```
Something went wrong
```

How can I fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need *two* conditions:  The user has to have a country, and that country has to have an image_url.  Only then will there be something to show.  Luckily, it's a simple tweak:

```
def image(user)
    if(user.country && user.country.image_url)
        image_tag "flags/#{user.country.image_url}.png" 
    end
end
```

If you're paranoid, you should make sure that `user` isn't `nil` either.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! It still returns this error `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):`

Comment: @HUSTEN - Glad that helped!  But I doubt that other error is related (especially since you never use addition here), so you'll have to track it down separately.

Answer (score 3):

While method chaining like that certainly works, your code will look a lot cleaner and become less coupled if you implement some method delegation.

Inside of your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

     belongs_to :country

     delegate :image_url, :to => :country, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => true       

end
```

Now your helper becomes simply:

```
def image(user)
    if user.country_image_url
        image_tag "flags/#{user.country_image_url}.png" 
    end
end
```

[Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) states:

> Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.

Also check out [Rail Best Practices Law of Demeter](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/15-the-law-of-demeter); if nothing else you're saving yourself the extra clause in your if statement & your code looks pretty.